# One-hot encoding to word2vec embedding

Tags: deep-learning, word2vec, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to create vectors for categorical information that I have at hand. This information is intended to be used for aiding seq2seq network for NLP purposes (like summarization).

To get the idea, maybe an example would be of help:

```
Sample Text: shark attacks off Florida in a 1-hour span
```

And suppose that we have this hypothetical categorical information:

```
1. [animal, shark, sea, ocean]
2. [animal, tiger, jungle, mountains]
...
19. [animal, eagle, sky, mountains]
```

I want to feed sample text to an LSTM network token-by-token (like seq2seq networks). I'm using pre-trained GloVe embeddings as my original embeddings which are fed into the network, but also want to concatenate a dense vector to each token denoting its category.

For now, I know that I can simply use the one-hot embeddings (0-1 binary). So, for example, the first input (for `shark`) to the RNN network would be:

```
# GloVe embeddings of shark + one-hot encoding for shark, + means concatenation
[-0.323 0.213 ... -0.134 0.934 0.031 ] + [1 0 0 0 0 ... 0 0 1]
```

The problem is that I have an extreme number of categories out there (around 20,000). After searching over the Internet, it seemed to me that people suggest using word2vec instead of one-hots. But, I can't get the underlying idea of how word2vec can demonstrate the categorical features in this case. Does anybody have a more clear idea?

Comment: Is that 'hypothetical categorical information' meant to be sets-of-categories that are applied to one text (such as your sample above), or alternate sets-of-categories for 19 different texts (not shown), or something else? Are the known-categories per-text or per-token? How were the known-categories assigned?

Comment: @gojomo Not exactly each sample, but these categories are applied to each 'token' in each sample. By this definition, the known categories are per-token. I'm mostly wondering whether I can transform these one-hot vectors to low-dimensional vectors trained with w2v approach.

Comment: I can't quite tell what you mean. Are any of those 0-to-19 hypothetical sets-of-categories meant as an example of the categories that would actually be applied to the lone word 'shark'? (If so, it's odd that there's also a category named 'shark'.) How were the known-categories assigned?

Comment: Sorry if I was somewhat unclear. I'd say each of these 19 hypothetical lines is a category. Like, in the first category,  'animal', 'shark', and 'fish' fall into the first category --I just edited the categories for you to get a better sense. You can consider these categories in the form of a tree, which has 'animal' as its root node, and a path from a leaf to the root indicates a category. 

I have a sheet that has these words along with their IDs and parent IDs. After gathering leaves with parents' (and ancedents') IDs, I got these categories. @gojomo

Answer (score 0):

Word2Vec can't be used for classification. It is just the underlying algorithm.

For classification you can use Doc2Vec or something similar.

It basically takes a list of documents and each has unique id assigned to it. After the training it builds relations between the documents similar to those which word2vec builds for the words. Then when you give it an unknown document it will tell you the top n most similar, and if your documents have previously defined tags you can assume that the unknown document can be labeled the same way.